# Can declarative authorization be used to hide/show certain fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization

I'm trying to figure out the best way to hide certain fields in user profile based on user's preference. So far I'm using a boolean field and an if, then statement.

```
<% if @user.show_email == 'true' -%>
  <%=h @user.email %>
<% else -%>
  hidden
<% end -%>
```

I was wondering if I could use declarative_authorization or some other better method that is more DRY. I prefer to have in a way like if @user.role == "admin" show all, if @user.role == "regular" show only non-hidden fields. etc

Thanks

Comment: Your question needs to be restated. In the first part and the code you are indicating that you want to query 'preferences' and 'profile' to control visibility and the second part you are describing a security based control.
Each present very different problem domains with very different possible solutions.

Comment: You're right it was awkwardly worded. Using has_role? combined with 'if, then' preferences options does what I want...except its one hell of a mess, bunch of 'if' and 'then' statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a helper function? In your case, I would do something like this on app/helpers/user_helper.rb:

```
def show_attribute(user, attribute_name)
  preference = "show_#{attribute_name}"

  if current_user.has_role?(:admin) or 
     !user.respond_to?(preference) or
     (user.respond_to?(preference) and user.send(preference))

    return user.send(attribute_name)
  else
    return "hidden"
  end

end
```

You can use it in your views like this:

```
  <%=h show_attribute(@user, :email) %>
  <%=h show_attribute(@user, :address) %>
```

Best regards.

Comment: No, I haven't, but that's a lot more DRY. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Someone slap me over the head for not reading the docs properly...it was right in front of my face.

You use the has_role? helper provided by d_a

```
<% if has_role?(:admin) %>
  show everything
<% else -%>
  show nothing
<% end -%>
```

I believe it passed in current_user automatically. So if current_user has role admin, its shows everything.